# Jenkinsfile write JSON file

Tags: java, json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

From within my Jenkinsfile, I am trying to create and write a simple JSON file to the workspace folder.

The contents of the JSON file should be:

```
{"people": {"name":"john","surname":"doe"}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should just be able to write that to a file instead of stdout? Have you considered using the StreamWriter? See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_streamingjsonbuilder

Comment: Is `JsonBuilder` serializable? I thought all the groovy JSON class methods were nonserializable. This seems like it would error.

Answer (score 6):

Got it!

```
script {
          def someMap = [
              'name' : "john",
              'surname' : "doe"
          ]
          def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
          json "people": someMap
          def file = new File("$WORKSPACE/people.json")
          file.write(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString()))
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writeJSON`: Write JSON to a file in the workspace.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace

Comment: I've tried that and got the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.WriteJSONStep.json expects interface net.sf.json.JSON but received class java.lang.String

Comment: can not help you with java. i'll add java tag to question.

Comment: I'm not using Java, but using plain old Groovy.

Comment: java platform, i've added both tags

Comment: @JoP It sounds like your usage of the method is wrong. Update your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any plugin, there is a workaround with the core Jenkins method `writeFile` e.g.:

```
writeFile(
    file: "foo/bar.json",
    text: """\
        {
            'a': 'x',
            'b': 'y'
        }
    """.stripIndent()
)
```